# Extracting Values after matching Attribute Values in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following **XML** File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <response>
<result name="response" numFound="10000" start="0">
    <doc>
        <str name="Title">Title 1</str>
        <str name="GUID">IMG_1</str>
        <str name="Desc">Desc 1</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <str name="Title">Title 2</str>
        <str name="GUID">IMG_2</str>
        <str name="Desc">Desc 2</str>
    </doc>
</result>
</response>
```

I would like to transform it into the following **HTML** file:

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                {Title}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://myserver/images/{GUID}">
            </td>
            <td>
                {Desc}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                {Title}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://myserver/images/{GUID}">
            </td>
            <td>
                {Desc}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
  </html>
```

Where the content in `{}` should be replaced from the **XML** file. I am curious how to do this using **XSL**. My attempt is as follows, but it comes out ***blank*** i.e. I get the **Table** structure, but no **Titles** or **Descriptions**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' >
<xsl:output media-type="text/html; charset=UTF-8" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match='/'>
    <html>
        <head> </head>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="response/result/doc"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:variable name="title" select="doc/str[@name='Title']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="guid" select="doc/str[@name='GUID']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="desc" select="doc/str[@name='Desc']"/>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://myserver/images/{GUID}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$desc"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd be grateful for any help as I am new to this.

Comment: How are you trying execute this. Is it in browser transformation or transformation happens server-side (with a server in place).

Comment: Thank you **madhav**. Right now I am doing this in **Visual Studio**, but it is irrelevant how the transformation happens. Anyway, the solutions below helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only some small errors in your xlst.
Because the current node for select for the variables in template doc is the doc element you have to remove the `doc/`.

```
<xsl:variable name="title" select="str[@name='Title']"/>
<xsl:variable name="guid" select="str[@name='GUID']"/>
<xsl:variable name="desc" select="str[@name='Desc']"/>
```

To add the variable value to the link use:

```
<img src="http://myserver/images/{$guid}" />
```

Therefore try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' >
    <xsl:output media-type="text/html; charset=UTF-8" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <html>
            <head> </head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="response/result/doc"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:variable name="title" select="str[@name='Title']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="guid" select="str[@name='GUID']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="desc" select="str[@name='Desc']"/>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://myserver/images/{$guid}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$desc"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you **hr_117**. This worked perfectly. I just edited your solution as far as the `<img/>` tag, because without it, it used to have `$guid` in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there you just added an extra "doc/"

since you are using

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
```

everything is relative to doc so you should only

```
<xsl:variable name="title" select="str[@name='Title']"/>
<xsl:variable name="guid" select="str[@name='GUID']"/>
<xsl:variable name="desc" select="str[@name='Desc']"/>
```